# translate english to hindi google transliterate

Tags: javascript, php

I want to translate English To Hindi Language and save it as a PHP variable.

This is official code from google. There is a text-area too for converted text.

Question: is there any way to Save this text in variable?

```
<html>
  <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Google Transliterate API
  google.load("elements", "1", {
        packages: "transliteration"
      });

  function onLoad() {
    var options = {
        sourceLanguage:
            google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.ENGLISH,
        destinationLanguage:
            [google.elements.transliteration.LanguageCode.HINDI],
        shortcutKey: 'ctrl+g',
        transliterationEnabled: true
    };

    // Create an instance on TransliterationControl with the required
    // options.
    var control =
        new google.elements.transliteration.TransliterationControl(options);

    // Enable transliteration in the textbox with id
    // 'transliterateTextarea'.
    control.makeTransliteratable(['transliterateTextarea']);
  }
  google.setOnLoadCallback(onLoad);
  </script>
  </head>
   <body>
  Type in Hindi (Press Ctrl+g to toggle between English and Hindi)<br>
   <textarea id="transliterateTextarea" style="width:600px;height:200px">   </textarea>
   </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Grab the contents and AJAX it to the server or wrap in a form tag and send it with a submit

Comment: I want converted to $text variable

Answer (score -1):

how about

```
var myVariable=document.getElementById("transliterateTextarea").innerText;

var xhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
// code for IE6, IE5
xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.open("GET", "myPhp.php?t=" + myVariable, true);
xhttp.send();
```

myPhp.php

```
if(isset($_GET['t']))$t = $_GET['t'];
```

Comment: Nope. Quoting the OP "and save it as a PHP variable." This is a JavaScript variable.

Comment: OK, I saw that after commenting. Have amended the answer to respond to the question more fully.

Comment: Please first fun this script There is a text box When we put text in box and hit enter or ctrl+g English text convert to hindi i want to get Hindi language text without put in the box

Comment: i want to convert Text using variable Not a Text Box